# Payment icon for private wallet

Tags: payment

I have a wallet created and stored on my computer that I use to accept donations. I want to make things easier for visitors by providing a payment button, but it seems all the online services that provide payment buttons only do so for wallets that you hold with them.

Is there a bitcoin broker somewhere that I can feed a wallet address that will process payments for a small fee?